# QGIS color sorting for string value column

Tags: gis, qgis

In `QGIS` I am trying to categorize a string value column.
It is a hydrological area code, in format `X-XX-XX-XXX, f.e. 3-01-01-001`.
i want them to be color categorized by the first 4 characters, `e.g. 3-01`.

is there a way to do this with string values?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwGhM.png)

Comment: came back here, saw this...did that help?

Answer (score 2):

Yep. In the *Symbology* tab in the *Layer Properties*

- select `Categorized` in the uppermost dropdown menu
- click the `epsilon` function symbol next to *Column*
- type `left("<field_name>", 4)` and hit *OK*
- click *Classify*

(You can also simply type that directly into the *Column* field, but it might be worth checking out the *Expression Dialog* and it´s options)

Btw.: for GIS related questions, come join us at [GIS SE](http://gis.stackexchange.com)!